# Cannot install Protractor 2.0.0 : ENOENT in bufferutil while node-gyp rebuild

Tags: node.js, selenium, protractor, node-gyp

Trying to install Protractor 2.0.0, I'm facing the following problem:

```
$ npm install -g protractor
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor
...
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan

> utf-8-validate@1.0.1 install C:\Users\clouderial\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\clouderial\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate {git}
{lamb} node "d:\Developpement\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at errnoException (child_process.js:998:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:34)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "d:\\Developpement\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\clouderial\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.28
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.0.1

> bufferutil@1.0.1 install C:\Users\clouderial\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\clouderial\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil {git}
{lamb} node "d:\Developpement\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at errnoException (child_process.js:998:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:34)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "d:\\Developpement\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\clouderial\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.28
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.0.1
C:\Users\clouderial\AppData\Roaming\npm\protractor -> C:\Users\clouderial\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor
C:\Users\clouderial\AppData\Roaming\npm\webdriver-manager -> C:\Users\clouderial\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\webdriver-manager
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\clouderial\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jmcnet\node_modules\grunt-contrib-watch requires lodash@'~2.4.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\clouderial\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jmcnet\node_modules\lodash,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.5.0
protractor@2.0.0 C:\Users\clouderial\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor
├── jasminewd@1.1.0
├── jasminewd2@0.0.3
├── html-entities@1.1.2
├── saucelabs@0.1.1
├── q@1.0.0
├── minijasminenode@1.1.1
├── adm-zip@0.4.4
├── lodash@2.4.1
├── accessibility-developer-tools@2.6.0
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10)
├── glob@3.2.11 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.3.0)
├── request@2.36.0 (forever-agent@0.5.2, qs@0.6.6, json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, aws-sign2@0.5.0, oauth-sign@0.3.0, mime@1.2.11, node-uuid@1.4.3, tough-cookie@0.12.1, http-signature@0.10.1, hawk@1.0.0, form-data@0.1.4)
├── jasmine@2.1.1 (jasmine-core@2.1.3)
├── source-map-support@0.2.10 (source-map@0.1.32)
└── selenium-webdriver@2.45.1 (tmp@0.0.24, rimraf@2.3.2, ws@0.7.1, xml2js@0.4.4)
```

I'm under Windows8 and I had to install Python (3.4.3) to achieve this installation.

My E2E tests are broken after this installation.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Jean-Marc

Comment: I try with Python 2.7 and still get an error message but different : MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Impossible de charger le composant Visual C++ "VCBuild.exe". Pour corriger le problème, vous devez 1) installer le Kit de développement .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) installer Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 ou 3) ajou ter l'emplacement du composant au chemin d'accès système, s'il est installé ailleurs.  [C:\Users\clouderial\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\binding .sln]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was 2 problems :
1. Python 2.7.x must be installed instead of Python 3.x,
2. An environment variable named PYTHON valued to path+python.exe must be set before running npm.

After this change the installation can continu (but is blocked here : [Installation of Protractor 2.0 and MSBUILD error MSB3428](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204994/installation-of-protractpr-2-0-and-msbuild-error-msb3428))

Jean-Marc.